# Route guard for authentication with ngrx store

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, angular-route-guards

I am trying to create an `AuthGuard` to check if an user can access a route, else, redirect to login view. I want to return an `Observable<Boolean|UrlTree>` from the
`canActivate` method. Here is what I have so far.

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {

    return this.store$.select(appState => appState.auth.authUser)
    .pipe(map(authUser => Boolean(authUser)));
}
```

However, I am not exactly sure how/where I can emit out an UrlTree from the observable to redirect to `/login`, since I am new to this whole thing, specially rxjs. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe just

```
  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.store$.select(appState => appState.auth.authUser)
      .pipe(map(authUser => {
        if (!authUser) {
          this._router.navigate(['route-to-your-login-page'])
        }
        return authUser;
      }))
  }
```

Simple and should work